# What is arithmetic left shift of 01001001?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I would think it is 00010010 
i.e. it tries to maintain the sign bit as is

On the other hand, the logical left shift by 1 pos would be
10010010

Is this correct?

Comment: @ajay By how many position(s)?

Comment: @JustinKSU Does it really matter? :)

Answer (score 12):

For left shift, arithmetic and logical shift are the same.

The difference is for right shift only, where an arithmetic right shift will copy the old MSB to the new MSB after having shifted, thus keeping a negative number from being converted to a positive when shifting.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) has a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6):

In Java `<<` is a logical left-shift. 0 is always added as the LSB.

(Do note that Java will *promote* the [byte] value in question, so care must be taken to *mask back* to an octect! Otherwise you'll keep the shifted bit(s), which might have included "1".)

However, the Wikipedia article on [Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) indiciates that an arithmetic left shift *may* result in an overflow error:

> ...***Note that arithmetic left shift may cause an overflow;*** this is the only way it differs from logical left shift.

(This is *not* the case in Java, but just to keep in mind.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct.

The arithmetic left shift of `x` by `n` places is equal to `x * (2^n)`. So in your example is the ar-left-shift of `01001001` by `1` place equal to `10010010` (73 * 2¹ = 146).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you left shift by 1 bit postion. It equals 10010010.

when you shift 4 bits to the left as follows, you get the following answer.

```
01001001 << 4 = 10010000
```

when you shift 4 bits to the right as follows, you get the following answer.

```
01001001 >> 4 = 00000100
```

Bits that are left empty as a result of shifting are filled with zeros.